# C# Console application - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel using Restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

Im trying to call a website but keeps getting the above error.

It's a console application (.net 4)

My method

```
public static Xmldata GetData(int productsPerPage, int pageNumber, RessourceType ressourceType)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
        request.RootElement = "xmldata";

        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = baseUrl + "?data=" + ressourceType.ToString() +
                                    "&key=" + key +
                                    "&output=xml&RowspPage=" + productsPerPage +
                                    "&PageNumber=" + pageNumber +
                                    "&dataonly=true";
        var response = client.Execute<Xmldata>(request);
        return response.Data;
    }
```

How to resolve ?

Answer (score -1):

I just upgraded to .Net 4.6.1 and that did it.